# Could not add Razor View using a layout page on macOS in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, razor-pages, visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual Studio for Macos. I need to add Razor View, but the use a layout page option in windows does not appear for me. How can I see the Use a layout page section?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? The former is not supported on macOS.

Comment: With an ASP.NET Core project you can right click the folder in the Solution window, and select Add - New Scaffolding, then select Razor Page. This will show a wizard with the layout page section. Note that, as Lex Li mentioned, ASP.NET is not supported only ASP.NET Core projects are.

Comment: @MattWard thank you so much